# jsp code when user is mobile

Tags: jsp, mobile

i'm trying to figure out the best way to create a mobile site (without relying strictly on media queries) from existing jsp and xsl code.  without resorting to a mobile only site, it has been discussed with the client that we use the current jsp pages and then serve different blocks of code depending on whether the user is on a mobile device or not.  Basically, i know i could hide/show different code with media queries but i'm trying to avoid serving extra code if at all possible.  Can anyone point me to any info on this or explain how this would be done?

Answer (score 3):

Use the user-agent to set a `mobile` flag in the user session to remember that the session is for a mobile device, and use

```
<c:if test="${!mobile}">...</c:if>
```

to only serve a given section of a JSP if the device it not a mobile device.

See http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ for how to detect a mobile browser.

Comment: thanks for this - i see on the detectmobilebrowsers site that this causes a redirect based on the user-agent - how would this be used to set the mobile flag as mentioned above?

Comment: It causes a redirect only because the code has `response.sendRedirect()` in the if block. This is just example code. Adapt it to set a flag in the session if you detect a mobile browser (and don't put this code in a JSP, but in a filter or interceptor).

Answer (score 0):

This helped me check mobile device

```
<c:set var="browser" value="${fn:toLowerCase(header['User-Agent'])}" />
```